# Implement dynamic status Java servlets and JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, servlets

I am developing a web server and My `home page` takes request from user and `/process` servlet processes the request by making calls to other classes and interacting with the database.
/process servlet executes a long running process ( needs to run a perl script using ProcessBuilder, takes 3 mins) and return back to `results.jsp?ID=something` page.

Now I am doing the following,
Taking request at `home.jsp --> /process servlet --> results.jsp`
I am not using process.waitFor(), so that my response goes quickly to results.jsp.
And in `results.jsp`, I am checking for the files (named with ID) to be generated by the `perl scrip`t and waiting for them to be generated and in meanwhile, I am showing status by refreshing the page every 15 seconds. Whenever the files are generated I am processing them in results.jsp and storing them in the database for further use with the query parameter `ID`.
And whenever user visits for the seconds time, results.jsp should not process everything, it should just grab the output from the database we previously stored.

Now I am doing too many database operations on results.jsp, but i feel this is the only way I can show them the dynamic status without changing the URL on browser.

Can you please help me out with any other effective way of doing things?

```
results.jsp?ID=1 draft
```

database.getOutput(ID) --- to get output corresponding to ID

```
<% if(ID!= null && database.getOutput(ID) == null) // checking for the first time
{
    checking for files on refresh
}
if(database.getOutput(ID) != null)
{
 pull details from databse and show here
}
```

Comment: you can try with Ajax queries also.

Comment: Can you please explain or provide me link on dynamic status. Status needs to b changed from time to time.